# here i want to filter out sucess entries from this string

Tags: java, pattern-matching

```
 String = "Success Entries and Failed Entries: {FAILED_ENTRIES=[], SUCCESS_ENTRIES=[1509230024960163905]}";
```

Here I want to filter out only

> `SUCCESS_ENTRIES` like **`1509230024960163905`**

```
String str = "Success Entries and Failed Entries: {FAILED_ENTRIES=[], SUCCESS_ENTRIES=[1509230024960163905,1509181140480153332]}";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=(SUCCESS_ENTRIES=\[)).+?(?=\])").matcher(str);
matcher.find();
str = matcher.group();
System.out.println(str);
matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\d{3}=)\\d+").matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Please show what you have done so far, some code snippets would be welcome. In general regular expressions are the right tool for this kind of a task.

Comment: String str ="Success Entries and Failed Entries: {FAILED_ENTRIES=[], SUCCESS_ENTRIES=[1509230024960163905,1509181140480153332]}";
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=(SUCCESS_ENTRIES=\\[)).+?(?=\\])").matcher(str);
  matcher.find();
  str = matcher.group();
  System.out.println(str);
  matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\d{3}=)\\d+").matcher(str);
  while(matcher.find()){
      System.out.println(matcher.group());
  }

 }

Comment: @KamleshKanazariya You need to [edit] your question to provide additonal details. You should not post code blocks in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String str = "Success Entries and Failed Entries: {FAILED_ENTRIES=[1509230024960163905], SUCCESS_ENTRIES=[1509230024960163905,1509181140480153332]}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("SUCCESS_ENTRIES=\\[(.*)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
for(String s: m.group(1).split("[^0-9]+"))
    if(!s.isEmpty())
        System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: can you explain this line str.split("[^0-9]+")   what it do in terms or regex

Comment: method `split` is separate string by regex pattern to `String[]`
A digit: [0-9]
A non-digit: [^0-9]
X, one or more times X+
see more http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
In our case we divide `String` and excluding non-digit

Comment: In above code if i put String like this "Success Entries and Failed Entries: {FAILED_ENTRIES=[15092300249601639051111], SUCCESS_ENTRIES=[1509181140480153332]}"; I got FAILED_ENTRIES also but i do not want to get FAILED_ENTRIES . only I want to SUCCESS_ENTRIES

Comment: can you help me Alexandr Dorokhin?

Comment: OK, try this `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("SUCCESS_ENTRIES=\\[([0-9]*)\\]");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group(1));
  }`

Comment: @KamleshKanazariya , Look at my example below. You just use pattern, which removes all unnecessary characters and convert your value to BigInteger.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy my friend. You should use a Regex pattern. You might create something like this http://ideone.com/IRIeYg Look at the following example. If you don't need `BigInteger`, easy use `Integer.valueOf(..)`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;

class MyClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String str1 = "Success Entries and Failed Entries: {FAILED_ENTRIES=[], SUCCESS_ENTRIES=[1509230024960163905,1509181140480153332]}";
        String str2 = "Success Entries and Failed Entries: {FAILED_ENTRIES=[435435435], SUCCESS_ENTRIES=[1509230024960163912]}";
        String pattern = "(Success[\\s]*Entries[\\s]*and[\\s]*Failed[\\s]*Entries[\\:]+"+
                 "[\\s]*['{']+FAILED_ENTRIES['=']+[\\[0-9\\]\\,]+[\\s]*" + 
                 "SUCCESS_ENTRIES['=']+[\\[]+)?(([\\s]?[\\,]+[0-9]*)?[\\]\\}]+)?";
        BigInteger successEntires1 = new BigInteger(str1.replaceAll(pattern, ""));
        BigInteger successEntires2 = new BigInteger(str2.replaceAll(pattern, ""));
        System.out.println(successEntires1);
        System.out.println(successEntires2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was modified, so your example doesn't work,

Comment: @AlexandrDorokhin, Oh, you're right. I changed my example. It's simple. Now every time you get only the first Integer from SUCCESS_ENTRIES.